# How to create SymBandedMatrix with chosen values?

Tags: julia

With the [`BandedMatrices`](https://github.com/JuliaMatrices/BandedMatrices.jl) package, is there a way to created a `SymBandedMatrix` with chosen values? There are a variety of constructors in docs, but none seem to accept input values. And indexing isn't implemented. Is that on purpose or just not done yet?

```
julia> using BandedMatrices

julia> a = BandedMatrices.SymBandedMatrix(Float64,5,1)
5×5 BandedMatrices.SymBandedMatrix{Float64}:
 6.90681e-310  6.90681e-310                                          
 6.90681e-310  6.90682e-310  6.90682e-310                            
               6.90682e-310  6.90682e-310  6.90681e-310              
                             6.90681e-310  6.90681e-310  6.90681e-310
                                           6.90681e-310  6.90684e-310

julia> a[1,1]=1
ERROR: indexing not defined for BandedMatrices.SymBandedMatrix{Float64}
Stacktrace:
 [1] setindex!(::BandedMatrices.SymBandedMatrix{Float64}, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64) at ./abstractarray.jl:966
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following could be an unpolished solution:

```
Base.setindex!(M::SymBandedMatrix,val,r,c) = 
  ( (a,b) = minmax(r,c) ; M.data[M.k+a-b+1,b-a+1]=val )
```

Giving for the code in the question:

```
julia> a = BandedMatrices.SymBandedMatrix(Float64,5,1)
5×5 BandedMatrices.SymBandedMatrix{Float64}:
 6.36578e-310  6.36578e-310                                          
 6.36578e-310  6.36578e-310  6.36577e-310                            
               6.36577e-310  6.36577e-310  6.36577e-310              
                             6.36577e-310  6.36577e-310  6.36578e-310
                                           6.36578e-310  6.36577e-310

julia> Base.setindex!(M::SymBandedMatrix,val,r,c) = 
         ( (a,b) = minmax(r,c) ; M.data[M.k+a-b+1,b-a+1]=val )

julia> a[1,1]=1
1

julia> a
5×5 BandedMatrices.SymBandedMatrix{Float64}:
 1.0           6.36578e-310                                          
 6.36578e-310  6.36578e-310  6.36577e-310                            
               6.36577e-310  6.36577e-310  6.36577e-310              
                             6.36577e-310  6.36577e-310  6.36578e-310
                                           6.36578e-310  6.36577e-310
```